# Writing a string from a function to a div element using the text() method in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, openx

Included below is the current code that I am using:

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
  function rightTopSidebarAd() {
    document.write ("Text to test!");  
  }
</script>

<div style="border:3px solid #FF0000" id="rightTopSidebar">

</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
   $j('#rightTopSidebar').text(rightTopSidebarAd());
</script>
```

Here I have a simple function `rightTopSidebarAd()` that I would like to return or print the string "Text to test!". I would like the function to result in the content being placed inside the `rightTopSidebar` element.

Currently it prints "Text to test!" just after the div because that is where the `text()` method is placed.  If I place the jQuery code above, then it is printed at that position.

*Note: I can not place the jQuery code inside the `div` because this is just a demo.  In the original page all the `div` elements will be spread around the webpage and I will have the jQuery functions stored in an external JavaScript file.*

EDIT: Guys, my fault: I did show a simple function

```
  function rightTopSidebarAd() {
    document.write ("Text to test!");  
  }
```

To illustrate my problem, as you say a simple "return" will fix this problem, but the real function is not so simple, I'm trying to return a OpenX code, please advice me how to do it with this function:

```
 function rightTopSidebarAd() {
    document.MAX_ct0 ='{clickurl}';

    var m3_u = (location.protocol=='https:'?'https://one.mydomain.com/www/delivery/ajs.php':'http://one.mydomain.com/www/delivery/ajs.php');
    var m3_r = Math.floor(Math.random()*99999999999);
    if (!document.MAX_used) document.MAX_used = ',';
    document.write ("<scr"+"ipt type='text/javascript' src='"+m3_u);
    document.write ("?zoneid=15&amp;target=_blank");
    document.write ('&amp;cb=' + m3_r);
    if (document.MAX_used != ',') document.write ("&amp;exclude=" + document.MAX_used);
    document.write (document.charset ? '&amp;charset='+document.charset : (document.characterSet ? '&amp;charset='+document.characterSet : ''));
    document.write ("&amp;loc=" + escape(window.location));
    if (document.referrer) document.write ("&amp;referer=" + escape(document.referrer));
    if (document.context) document.write ("&context=" + escape(document.context));
    if ((typeof(document.MAX_ct0) != 'undefined') && (document.MAX_ct0.substring(0,4) == 'http')) {
        document.write ("&amp;ct0=" + escape(document.MAX_ct0));
    }
    if (document.mmm_fo) document.write ("&amp;mmm_fo=1");
    document.write ("'><\/scr"+"ipt>");
    document.write ("<noscript><a href='http://one.mydomain.com/www/delivery/ck.php?n=a8ed906c&amp;cb={random}' target='_blank'><img src='http://one.mydomain.com/www/delivery/avw.php?zoneid=15&amp;cb={random}&amp;n=a8ed906c&amp;ct0={clickurl}' border='0' alt='' /></a></noscript>");
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to return your value instead of writing it to document:

```
function rightTopSidebarAd() {
   return "Text to test!";  
}
```

According to your question update, your function now should be:

```
function rightTopSidebarAd() {
    var valueToReturn = '';
    document.MAX_ct0 ='{clickurl}';

    var m3_u = (location.protocol=='https:'?'https://one.mydomain.com/www/delivery/ajs.php':'http://one.mydomain.com/www/delivery/ajs.php');
    var m3_r = Math.floor(Math.random()*99999999999);
    if (!document.MAX_used) document.MAX_used = ',';
    valueToReturn += "<scr"+"ipt type='text/javascript' src='"+m3_u;
    valueToReturn += "?zoneid=15&amp;target=_blank";
    valueToReturn += '&amp;cb=' + m3_r;
    if (document.MAX_used != ',') valueToReturn += "&amp;exclude=" + document.MAX_used;
    valueToReturn += document.charset ? '&amp;charset='+document.charset : (document.characterSet ? '&amp;charset='+document.characterSet : '');
    valueToReturn += "&amp;loc=" + escape(window.location);
    if (document.referrer) valueToReturn += "&amp;referer=" + escape(document.referrer);
    if (document.context) valueToReturn += "&context=" + escape(document.context);
    if ((typeof(document.MAX_ct0) != 'undefined') && (document.MAX_ct0.substring(0,4) == 'http')) {
        valueToReturn += "&amp;ct0=" + escape(document.MAX_ct0);
    }
    if (document.mmm_fo) valueToReturn += "&amp;mmm_fo=1";
    valueToReturn += "'><\/scr"+"ipt>";
    valueToReturn += "<noscript><a href='http://one.mydomain.com/www/delivery/ck.php?n=a8ed906c&amp;cb={random}' target='_blank'><img src='http://one.mydomain.com/www/delivery/avw.php?zoneid=15&amp;cb={random}&amp;n=a8ed906c&amp;ct0={clickurl}' border='0' alt='' /></a></noscript>";
    return valueToReturn;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Antyrat for your answer, but the real function that I use can not be solved with a simple return, I edited the description to show the function, please apology my fault.

Comment: @Saymon well then you need to rewrite your function using string concatenations, otherwise you can't get expected result.

Comment: do you have an example how to do the string concatenations to make sure I'm understanding fine.

Comment: Antyrat: Now the js code is placed in the correct div, but now it is printed as plain text instead execute the code itself, any ideas ?

Answer (score 1):

Simply return text from your function instead of printing it:

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
  function rightTopSidebarAd() {
    return "Text to test!";  
  }
</script>

<div style="border:3px solid #FF0000" id="rightTopSidebar">

</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
   $j('#rightTopSidebar').text(rightTopSidebarAd());
</script>
```

Comment: Hi des, thanks for your answer, I edited my description to show the real function that I have the problem, it is more complex than function rightTopSidebarAd() {
    return "Text to test!";  
  }
so I believe that need more than a return, please take a look, thanks so much again

Comment: My solution wouldn't change, just save all text into variable (instead of `document.write`) and return it all (e.g. `myVariable += '&amp;cb=' + m3_r;`instead of `document.write ('&amp;cb=' + m3_r);`)

Answer (score 1):

Your current method attempts to write to the document object, not the `#rightTopSidebar`.

Try the following update to your function:

```
function rightTopSidebarAd() {     
    return "Text to test!";     
}
```

By utilizing return, you are passing the string to the `text()` method, which will result in the passed string being written to the desired element.

In addition, you will need to call the text() method by either encasing your code in the [`$(document).ready()`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) function.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function rightTopSidebarAd() {
    return "Text to test!";
} 
$(function(){
    $('#rightTopSidebar').text(rightTopSidebarAd());
});
</script>
<div style="border:3px solid #FF0000" id="rightTopSidebar"></div >
```

Comment: It attempts not to write object. It attempt to write `undefined` as his function doesn't return anything.

Comment: @antyrat - 'Right now it prints "Text to test!" just after the div because there is where I have the jquery function, if I place the jquery code above, then is printed there."

Comment: Yeah, but in jQuery `text()` it pass `undefined`

Comment: @antyrat - That is incorrect.  As the page is loaded and evaluated, the `document.write` function is executed when referenced using the `text()` method.  During the execution, the string is written to the document object.  Nothing is technically passed as that is not the current implementation, but `undefined` would indicate that an undefined variable was passed, which is not the case.  Please see http://jsfiddle.net/jCHsp/.

Comment: Thanks RobB for your answer, I just edited the description to show the real function to use, it is more complex that the one I illustrated my example, I thanks an answer for this one :)